# strategy.entry. How to enter inside bar?

Tags: pine-script

How to enter a trade inside the bar, not at the close?

I tried to use "magnifier on" but it did not help.

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("Sell Stop", "Long", stop=lastOppositeFractalDown)
lastStop := lastOppositeFractalDown
```

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.entry()` will enter with a market order by default. If you want to place limit orders, you need to use the `limit` or `stop` arguments.

> ***limit (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Limit price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'limit', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.
>
> ***stop (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Stop price of the order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'stop', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.